# Are passkeys anonymous?

Tags: anonymity, passkey

I was considering using passkeys as a 1FA. I wanted users to login/register without email or password and without logging their IP.

But being anonymous would probably bring very bad things to any site.

So question is: is using passkeys anonymous? Can users be traced back to their IP or cloud accounts in case of them doing something nasty?

Comment: Passkeys don't eliminate identity... and they don't replace IPs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So question is: is using passkeys anonymous? Can users be traced back to their IP or cloud accounts in case of them doing something nasty?

Passkeys doesn't change what a service sees. It's a piece of information that can be used for authentication, just like a password. They will not hide your IP or increase your anonymity.

> I basically wanted users to login/register without email or password and without logging their IP.

Then don't ask your users for e-mail address and don't log IP's.